# How to sort dataframe by multiple columns simultaneously

Tags: r, sorting

Essentially, I wish to know how to sort a data frame into categories based on one column and then, within those categories, sort the data frame again based on another column. So say we have the following data frame df:

```
ID          date     value

current2    01/2018  1
current2    03/2018  2
past1       03/2012  4
past1       01/2012  3
current2    09/2018  7
past2       11/2012  1
current1    01/2018  2
current1    03/2018  8
current1    05/2018  13
current2    07/2018  2
past2       09/2012  5
current1    07/2018  1
current2    05/2018  2
past1       05/2012  4
past2       07/2012  3
current2    11/2018  7
past2       05/2012  1
current1    09/2018  2
current1    11/2018  8
past1       07/2012  13
past1       09/2012  2
past1       11/2012  5
past2       03/2012  2
past2       01/2012  5
```

I would like to sort the data in increasing order by the number component of ID (with the 'past' version coming before the 'current' and then, within those subcategories, I would like to then sort by month in ascending order. My desired output is the following:

```
ID          date     value

past1       01/2012  3
past1       03/2012  4
past1       05/2012  4
past1       07/2012  13
past1       09/2012  2
past1       11/2012  5
current1    01/2018  2
current1    03/2018  8
current1    05/2018  13
current1    07/2018  1
current1    09/2018  2
current1    11/2018  8
past2       01/2012  5
past2       03/2012  2
past2       05/2012  1
past2       07/2012  3
past2       09/2012  5
past2       11/2012  1
current2    01/2018  1
current2    03/2018  2
current2    05/2018  2
current2    07/2018  2
current2    09/2018  7
current2    11/2018  7
```

I have tried many different solutions but I can't seem to figure out the even the basic idea of how to sort by two columns like this. Help would be much appreciated

Comment: @MartinGal  This question's tittle is not very  clear.  In fact,  this question is  more restricted because it assigns the customed order of `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(index = str_sub(ID, -1)) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(index, desc(ID), date) %>% 
  select(-index)
```

Edit: `str_sub` comes from the package `stringr`

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` solution could be

```r
df[with(df, order(regmatches(ID, regexpr("\\d+$", ID)), -rank(ID), date)),]
```

which returns

```
        ID    date value
1     past1 01/2012     3
2     past1 03/2012     4
3     past1 05/2012     4
4     past1 07/2012    13
5     past1 09/2012     2
6     past1 11/2012     5
7  current1 01/2018     2
8  current1 03/2018     8
9  current1 05/2018    13
10 current1 07/2018     1
11 current1 09/2018     2
12 current1 11/2018     8
13    past2 01/2012     5
14    past2 03/2012     2
15    past2 05/2012     1
16    past2 07/2012     3
17    past2 09/2012     5
18    past2 11/2012     1
19 current2 01/2018     1
20 current2 03/2018     2
21 current2 05/2018     2
22 current2 07/2018     2
23 current2 09/2018     7
24 current2 11/2018     7
```